# I have ItemResource reference in data written into redis

Tags: laravel, redis, predis, laravel-resource

I use resources on api site to extend data(labels, formatting, related data ...).

But when I used ItemResource writing into redis :

```
$activeItems = Item::with('creator')->getByPublished(true)->get();
foreach( $activeItems as $item ) {
    $redisUniqueKey = CachingDataTypeEnum::cdtItem . '_' . $item->id;
    Redis::set($redisUniqueKey, serialize( new ItemResource($item->toArray())) );
    Redis::expire($redisUniqueKey, $itemsCachingHours * 3600 *100);
    $generatedItemsCount++;
}
```

Resulting item under redis has header like :

```
O:34:"App\Http\Resources\ItemResource":3:{s:8:"resource";a:10:{s:2:"id";i:4;s:5:"title";s:37:"Item C...
```

I dislike this ItemResource reference and wonder could it raise some problems in future using of these redis data ?

How it can be fixed ?
"laravel/framework": "^9.47",
"predis/predis": "^2.1",

Comment: You mean the namespace magically changes during development? If that is the case, the cache has to be emptied anyway, so no, if the data is not persistent, it doesn’t matter.

Comment: Not sure that I understood you message. I dislike App\Http\Resources\ItemResource in redis item...

Comment: Yes because of the namespace, as I said in the previous comment

Comment: Redis is being used here as a memory cache store right? Is it being used for persistent storage?

Comment: I have a task making with eloquent application with mysql used for data storage to make it also compatible with redis.
 I am new in redis - just search search how that can be done.

Comment: Ok, so `redis` is used as a cache and `mysql` is used as the persistent data storage, e.g. database. The namespace `App\Http\Resources\ItemResource` in cache (`redis`) is not a problem, because during development and updating sources, you have to clear out the cache anyway. If not, and parts of the cache have be present, you have to use multiple connections set with different database parameters. I'm wondering why you are using the `Redis` class and not the `Cache` class to store the `Redis::set($redisUniqueKey)` part for example.

Comment: Are Cache class methods preferable in comparison with methods of Redis class ?

Comment: Yes they are, please consult Laravels documentation about caching and database access